# Hide long text in table but keep access to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

I'm trying to cut a long text in a `<td>` but keep access to the data inside it. Maybe like on mobile by clicking and dragging inside the area.

My first idea was to use `max-width` and `overflow` but we have a big **scrollbar** under it (even if we can customize it I know) and it's not really easy to use. If we hide the scrollbar we can't scroll.

Here is an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Mossart/aq9Laaew/209397/

[image]

---

**What I would like to achieve:**

- Be able to double click and have access to the data (like now)
- Still be able to see the entire path of the file by maybe dragging like on mobile, click/drag
- No scrollbar or something better

I didn't find any good **UX** alternative if I want to keep a fixed width in my `<td>`. Any ideas without too much coding ?

Comment: Perhaps more of a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com?

Comment: How about you make a text elipsis and when you click/hover you show the full text in a "helper label"?

Comment: You could use the `:focus` selector to set `white-space: normal` when a user clicks on the td element. You also need to set the `tabindex="0"` attribute on each td to make it focusable.

Comment: The best way to show the text is using a "Tooltip". For a quick fix you can have in 'title' attribute. If it is so important to show the text, then use collapse the tr and show it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the title attribute doesn't exactly work on mobile.

Comment: `white-space: normal` can be interesting but it break the layout and I would like to avoid it. Tooltip may be a better way if we can combine it with the overflow

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to allow line wrapping when a user focuses on the table data element. Whether you want to use this is up to you.

**Working example:**

```css
td {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td:focus {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
            <td tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that `tabindex="0"` is required to make the `<td>` elements focusable.

You could use this CSS instead to avoid the page jumping.

```
td {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
td:focus {
    white-space: normal;
    border-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property for your mobile `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`